# Problem in Obj-c to access to previously defined C Struct data

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, memory-management

I'm new on objc/Cocoa and I never use C before.

I've a problem to get previously defined C struct data…
Here's my code :

AppController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject {
    AuthorizationRef authRef;
    AuthorizationRights authRights;
    AuthorizationFlags authFlags;
}
- (IBAction)toggleAuthentification:(id)sender;
@end
```

AppController.m

```
#import "AppController.h"

@implementation AppController
    - (id)init {
        if (![super init])
            return nil;

        AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authRef);
        AuthorizationItem rightItems[1] = {{"com.myname.myapp.adminRights", 0, NULL, 0}};
        authRights.count = 1;
        authRights.items = rightItems;
        authFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize;

        return self;
    }

    - (IBAction)toggleAuthentification:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"%d", AuthorizationCopyRights(authRef, &authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, authFlags ^ kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed, NULL));
    }
@end
```

When I click on a button in my app that call `toggleAuthentification:`, I get error code -60008 (errAuthorizationInternal).
In the debugger I can see `authRights.count` = 1, that correct, but `authRights.items` do not correspond in any way to data defined in `init`.

I try many different way but I don't find solution.

Please, anyone can explain why it doesn't work like I would it work and how to resolve my problem.

Bil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is memory management.

When you create `rightItems[]`, an array of `AuthorizationItem` elements, it is created in the stack since `rightItems[]` is an automatic (local) variable. This means that the memory used by the array is deallocated at the end of the method. Since you’re assigning `rightItems[]` to `authRights.items`, `authRights.items` points to a bogus memory address after `-init` has finished executing. Any further reference to `authRights.items` has undefined behaviour and is likely to produce an error in your program.

What you need to do is to create the array in the heap so that it isn’t deallocated when `-init` has finished executing. You can do that via `malloc()`. For instance:

```
const size_t numberOfRightItems = 1;
AuthorizationItem *rightItems = malloc(sizeof(AuthorizationItem)
    * numberOfRightItems);
rightItems[0] = (AuthorizationItem){"com.myname.myapp.adminRights", 0, NULL, 0};

authRights.items = rightItems;
```

*In theory*, you’re responsible for releasing authRights.items when it’s not needed any longer since you’ve allocated memory for it in the heap. Hence, in your `-dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    free(authRights.items);
    super[dealloc];
}
```

I’ve said *in theory* because you’re storing the authorisation rights in your application controller. Since the application controller lives throughout the application lifecycle, technically it won’t receive `-release` or `-dealloc`. However, it’s good practice and potentially useful in case you rearchitect your application and that code ends up being in a class whose objects are not necessarily alive until the application exits.

One further note: you should assign the return value of `[super init]` to `self` in your `-init` method. This is also good practice since it is possible that `[super init]` returns a different object than current `self`.

Comment: Thank Bavarious for explanation and solution, it's work perfectly. I was thinking that variables defined in function scope AND referenced in global variable was automatically keep in memory. And now I'll use `self = [super init]; if (!self)return nil;`